# How to split the 2 IP addresses appended by google cloud load balancer

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apache-2.4, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

I am using apache as my webserver for drupal. Also, I am using google cloud CDN and my instance is behind a load balancer (requirement for google cloud CDN). The issue is that the load balancer appends 2 IP addresses to the x-forwrded-for header as mentioned in this support document - https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https#target-proxies

I want to split those IPs in apache's log and only keep the client IP from the 2 IP addresses that it appends. Please help

Comment: You'll want https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_remoteip.html.

Answer (score 1):

`LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" \"%{x-forwarded-for-first}e\"" combined`
`SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For "^([^,]+)" x-forwarded-for-first=$1`

This will produce logs in the following format:
`127.0.0.1 - - [23/Dec/2022:12:34:56 +0100] "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 200 123 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.82 Safari/537.36" "203.0.113.45"`

The SetEnvIf directive uses the ^ character to match the start of the X-Forwarded-For header, and the ([^,]+) regular expression to match and capture the first IP address. The captured IP address is then stored in the x-forwarded-for-first environment variable.